# What's the difference between Random.rand(x) and just rand(x) in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Are they both exactly the same?

e.g.

```
rand(100)   #=> 12
```

and

```
Random.rand(100)   #=> 12
```

Comment: There's also [`Random#rand`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Random.html#rand-method), i.e. an instance method. It allows you to have multiple instances with different / independent seeds. And of course [`SecureRandom`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) which isn't based on the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation for `Random#rand` mentions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Random.html#method-i-rand),

> Unlike Kernel#rand, when max is a negative integer or zero, rand raises an ArgumentError.

Otherwise, they have the same behavior.

Comment: Also, if `x` is a `Float` then `rand(x)` returns an `Integer` whereas `Random.rand(x)` returns a `Float`. This is all documented in the above link,

Comment: cool, thanks, I didn't know that Kernel#rand meant just rand